# Display alert message using Form Script in Netsuite OpenAir in Project record

Tags: javascript, openair

I have written a "Form script" for Project record in Netsuite-OpenAir. I would like to display an alert message on clicking on the "Save" button in Project record. 
The code that I have currently written in the form script is:

```
NSOA.meta.alert('Form Alert Message');
```

But it seems that this alert message is only displayed in the Form script log and not on the Project record (when clicked on Save). I also tried the traditional Javascript "alert('Form Alert');" message. But this to did not work. 
Hence how do I display an alert message in the Form script and prevent the user from saving the form?

Also a form script in OpenAir executes on 3 events namely: On Submit, Before Save and After Save. So how do I execute an onChange function when a field value is changed? Rather than executing a function on submit of the form?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The format to display an error is

```
 NSOA.form.error('field', 'message');
```

There is no onChange event in OpenAir